# Make holder.js same size as other bootstrap thumbnail images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, holder.js

I have a row where one has an image, but the other does not and uses holder.js as a placeholder.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="holder.js/100%x100%"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My css for thumbnail is:

```
.thumbnail > img {
    width: 45%;
}
```

holder.js doesn't fit the image to bootstrap's thumbnail width and height. It's generating a 248x20 size placeholder image, which is way too small height. The width looks find though.

How do I make the placeholder images the same dimensions as the bootstrap thumbnail images?

Comment: Set the size of the holder.js to be the same dimensions as the image you're trying to match.  In other words, if your image.jpg is 400px by 400px then use: src="holder.js/400x400"

Answer (score 1):

Specify height not in percentage `<img src="holder.js/100%x75">`
[Official documentation](https://github.com/imsky/holder#fluid-placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you don't have an explicit height set on the `.thumbnail` class. Because of this, when Holder tries to get the height of the placeholder's parent, it gets an incorrect value. Set the height of `.thumbnail` and your code should work.